# Adding Azure Ad Oauth2 JWT Token Claims

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, claims

I was just wondering if there is a way to add or specify custom claims to the Azure Ad OAuth2 JWT token via Azure Portal?
Or is this only possible code side?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Azure AD doesn't support to issue the custom claim at present.

As a workaround, we can use the Azure AD Graph to add the [directory schema extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#ReadAnExtensionValue). After that, we can use the Azure AD Graph to get the data extension and add the custom claim when the security token is verified like code below:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = context => 
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            ,
            SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                //you can use the Azure AD Graph to read the custom data extension here and add it to the claims 
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("AddByMe", "test"));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
    });
```

In addition if you have any idea or feedback about Azure, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Ok, i understand, that can maybe be an option for me. but what i am looking for is to include a deviceID claim in the jwt token issued by azure AD. and i found some information about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/mdm/azure-active-directory-integration-with-mdm 

Under the topics: "Terms of Use protocol semantics" and "Management protocol with Azure AD"

Is this only applyable for a BYOD subscription or am i missunderstanding this? @FeiXue Thanks for the answer btw :)

Comment: @John Thanks for sharing the answer with us. I suggest that you compose a post and mark it as answer so that others who have the same issue could recolonize it easily and could benefit from it:)

Comment: sorry maybe i was a bit unclear in my question above. I hadn't found the solution, I was simply asking in referencing the link above: Am I able to include device-id in the claims of the bearer token, or is this only possible in a BYOD subscription? Best Wishes. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confutation. I suggest that you reopen an new thread about MDM since I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could get an example on how to set additional claims (Role claims for instance) by reading the [How to run the sample as a single-tenant app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims#case-2-how-to-run-the-sample-as-a-single-tenant-app) part of the [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims)  Azure-AD sample. This requires editing the Azure-AD application manifest to add application roles. Then assign different roles to different users in the directory

Comment: Well, I don't think it is valid to say "custom" in a context of Roles claims. As for literally **custom** claims - that is not possible to achieve.