# Including Device ID in Bearer Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, mdm, bearer-token, claims, refresh-token

Is it Possible to somehow include Device_ID and information about the device in Bearer token Claims, or is this only Possible through a BYOD MDM subscription?

I have read about this for some while now and haven't found anything to make this happen, though there are hints around pointing at for example the refresh_token containing that information (Which i haven't found a way to check just yet).

[Device_ID in refresh_token](https://jairocadena.com/2016/11/08/how-sso-works-in-windows-10-devices/)

Also Reading about MDM (Mobile Device Management) this is possible it seems.

[About BYOD and MDM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/mdm/azure-active-directory-integration-with-mdm) Under the topics:

"Terms of Use protocol semantics" and "Management protocol with Azure AD"

i have also asked about "custom" claims before (with no luck, unfortunately) and was asked to repost a more specific question.

[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434254/adding-azure-ad-oauth2-jwt-token-claims/42478752?noredirect=1#comment72113330_42478752)

Comment: The question is heaps too ambiguous. Yes, if you are the MDM vendor integrating with Azure, you will get the device id in the claims, it is true. However, you need a paid Azure subscription and Microsoft-enabled app in the Azure app store. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @zaitsman Well i think the question was pretty clear by the first 2 rows actually, but sorry for being unclear i guess :P

Is it possible to somehow include Device_ID and information about the device in Bearer token Claims, OR is this only possible through a BYOD MDM subscription? 

Ie: Is including Device ID in bearer token possible without a BYOD MDM subscription?

Comment: Yes, it is possible without BYOD MDM subscription.

Comment: Any possibility you know how this is done or know of a guide or dokument explaining this in more detail? Would be much appreciated :) @zaitsman

Comment: You have to contact your representative at Microsoft and ask them to register your app as the MDM app in Azure Marketplace